# ElementHost repainting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, avalonedit, elementhost

I'm using *AvalonEdit* in my *WinForms* application. *AvalonEdit* is placed onto control with *ElementHost* on it. Application has *RadDock* from Telerik and *AvalonEdit* can be placed on its windows. Often I get problem with *ElementHost* repainting. I don't know all the symptoms, but I can reproduce this problem by changing focus and moving other windows over the editor. After this all WPF controls in my application become broken and can't be repainted. The only way to force to redraw *ElementHost* is resizing. I can change for example width and WPF control will be redrawn. But this "solution" is not acceptable. The problem can be reproduced for docked or floating windows, for windows with active scrollbars or without, on x64 and x86 machine. To "fix" *ElementHost* I need to restart application.
Have somebody any suggestion for me?

Comment: At least check if the problem disappears when you don't put it in a RadDock.  If not then you have something to talk about when you call Telerik for support.

Comment: I have created separate application which has RadDock and AvalonEdit, and I couldn't reproduce this problem. Probably this freezing is related to counts of controls in application, or numbers of layers from MainForm to AvalonEdit.